# If value in Row 2 appears in Row 1 then change the cell colour in Row 3

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I rarely use `Excels` more advanced functions.

I've been playing around with `conditional` formats and `vlookups` etc trying to get something to work which is probably easy to someone with experience.

I've attached a screenshot of my test sheet. Basically `row 1` is a *variable row*, the numbers in there will change.

`Row 2` is *static*, the numbers won't change and it is a row of reference numbers. Not used for anything else.

What I'd like is a formula for `Row 3` that colours the cell if the number above it also appears in `Row 1`.

So for `cell G5` the logic is, if the number above me `(6)` appears anywhere in `Row 1`, then change `G5` to green.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help

kind rgds

TP

Example screenshot

[image]

Recommended formula error

[image]

Comment: I'll have an answer for you in a couple minutes...  in the meantime, I hate to tell ya, but Conditional Formatting isn't anywhere *near* as advanced (and complicated!) Excel can get!  :)

Comment: Thanks, no problem. For me it is as advanced as I will ever need to get ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional Formatting along with a `MATCH` Formula is a simple way to accomplish this.

[image: Screenshot]

---

- Using your example, enter this formula in cell `G5`:

  `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G4,$B$1:$K$1,0)))`

> This formula returns `TRUE` if the value "above it" (`G4`) is found in range `B1:K1`.  (Note the $Dollar Signs, so that cell reference is "locked in place" when we copy the formula elsewhere.)

- Select `G5` again and then click `Conditional Formatting` on the ribbon, and choose **"Highlight Cell Rules** and then **Equal To...**.
- In the conditional formatting dialog's `EQUAL TO:` box, enter `=TRUE`.
- In the drop-down menu, choose `Custom Format...`, and then select your **Green Fill** and also make the **Text Color** the same.  Click OK twice.
- Copy cell `G5` and paste itr into the cells `B5:K5`.

Now the cells will change colour as you described!

---

### More Information:

- ExcelUniversity : [Conditional Formatting Based on Another Cell](https://www.excel-university.com/excel-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell/)
- Office.com : [Use formulas with Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)
- Tech Republic :  [10 Cool Ways to use Conditional Formatting](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-cool-ways-to-use-excels-conditional-formatting-feature/)
- Microsoft Support : **[Excel video training](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-video-training-9bc05390-e94c-46af-a5b3-d7c22f6990bb)**

Comment: Monstrous answer!  I'm away from the office a few hours but know it will work already from your recording. Thanks so much, not only does it answer this query but I can already think of ways I can apply the different steps to other excel stuff I do. Top contributor

Comment: You're welcome!  I added some links to my answer which would benefit you (especially the last link)... You may think you know all you'll need to about Excel, but there's some pretty exciting stuff ahead once you get more comfortable with the basics.  :)

Comment: Yeah I saw them thanks, I already got them bookmarked for future reference. As I've been a lurker on here and just joined I don't get upvotes just yet but am closing in. I'll be back to click those arrows when allowed ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that silly rule, just like the images I meant to fix in your question since you're not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for protecting us newbs

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into cell `B5`:

```
=SUM((B4=$B$1:$K$1)*1)
```

After inserting this formula don't simply press Return but Ctrl+Shift+Return. In this way you are creating a formula array. If you did it right you will see curly brackets around your formula in the formula bar.

Copy this formula to all relevant cells in row 5.

After that you can apply a custom format `;;;` to these cells to avoid that the number is shown. And then a conditional format to color all cells containing a number greater then 0.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that formula but it looks to be erroring out unless I'm doing it wrong. Took a screenshot and will attach to the OP

Comment: @tigrepojke: Yes, sorry, I used the German function name by mistake :-). I fixed it for completeness

Answer (score 0):

Clear any existing Conditional Formatting from and select B5:K5, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF($B1:$K1,B4)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.